# Regex for uppercase matches with exclusions

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I'm trying to come up with a regex for the following case: I need to find any matching paths using `grep` for the following paths:

- Include all uppercase matching paths.
  Example:

  com/foo/Bar/1.2.3-SNAPSHOT/Bar-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT.jar

  Notice the capital `B` in `Bar`.
- Exclude all uppercase matching paths that only contain `SNAPSHOT` and have no other uppercase letters.
  Example:

  com/foo/bar/1.2.3-SNAPSHOT/bar-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT.jar

Is this possible with `grep`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this might do:

```
grep -vE '^([^[:upper:]]*(SNAPSHOT)?)*$'
```

Breakdown:

`-v` will reverse the match (show all non matched lines. `-E` enabled Extended Regular Expressions.

```
^                             # Start of line
 (                        )*  # Capturing group repeated zero or more times
  [^[:upper:]]*               # Match all but uppercase zero or more times
               (SNAPSHOT)?    # Followed by literal SNAPSHOT zero or one time
                            $ # End of line
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple example and the detailed breakdown for mortals like myself!

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to get the matching files. I'll do it like this.

```
find . -type f -regex '.*[A-Z].*' | while read -r line; do echo "$line" | sed 's/SNAPSHOT//g' | grep -q '.*[A-Z].*' && echo "$line"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use awk:

```
$ cat file
com/foo/Bar/1.2.3-SNAPSHOT/Bar-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
com/foo/bar/1.2.3-SNAPSHOT/bar-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

With GNU awk or mawk for gensub():

```
$ awk 'gensub(/SNAPSHOT/,"","g")~/[[:upper:]]/' file
com/foo/Bar/1.2.3-SNAPSHOT/Bar-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

With other awks:

```
$ awk '{r=$0; gsub(/SNAPSHOT/,"",r)} r~/[[:upper:]]/' file
com/foo/Bar/1.2.3-SNAPSHOT/Bar-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need `find` to list all paths. Then you can do it with `grep` with two runs. One includes all capital cases. The other one excludes that contain no capitals except `SNAPSHOT`:

```
find . | grep '[A-Z]' | grep -v '.*\/[^A-Z]*SNAPSHOT[^A-Z]*$'
```

I think only the last grep needs some explanation:

- `grep -v` **excludes** the matching lines
- `.*\/` *greedily* matches everything up to the first slash. There'll always be a slash due to `find .`
- `[^A-Z]*` finds all characters that are non-capital letters. So we apply it before and after the SNAPSHOT literal, up to the end of the string.

[Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMQjhXQ2h5RWF6ems) you can play with it online.